# I have a JSON array with 4 elements in angular 7, but it shows 0 when I asked for it`s length

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have an API that responds a JSON object to request. Everything looks normal but when I want to access to elements of this JSON Array it shows 0 elements instead of true value.

it's my request :

```
private request(type: 'getall'|'getonebyid'|'addnew'|'editbyid'|'deleteonebyid',
                  mp?: IMeasurementInterfaces,
                  id?: string): Observable<any> {
  let base;
  this.serverUri = 'http://localhost:3000'; // localhost

  if (type === 'getall') {
    base = this.http.get<MeasurementDetails[]>(`${this.serverUri}/mea/${type}`);
  }
  const request = base.pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      return data;
    })
  );
  return request;
}
```

call request function :

```
public getall(): Observable<MeasurementDetails[]> {
    return this.request('getall');
}
```

filling mpserv declared in component.ts file:

```
this.mpserv.getall().subscribe(
  x => {
    x.forEach(element => {
      this.mp.push(element);
    });
  },
  err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification')
);
```

when I request console.log(this.mpserv) it responds this:[image: developer mode]

I used this.mp as data source of data table :

```
<div class="measurement-type-grid">
<div class="measurement-type-list">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- title Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> title </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- description Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> description </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Edit Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Edit </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Edit data">edit</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Delete Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Delete data">delete_forever</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Add New Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="add new">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Add New </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Delete data">add_circle</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
</div>
```

I used this function to fill data to data source:

```
filltoelements(mdata: MeasurementDetails[]) {
// console.log(mdata);
if (!mdata) {
  console.log('data is undefined!!!!');
} else {
  let i: number;
  i = -1;
  mdata.forEach(element => {
    i++;
    this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].position = i + 1;
    this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].title = element.measureTitle;
    this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].description = element.measureDescription;
    this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].symbol = element.measureSymbol;
    this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].edit = 'edit';
    this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].delete = 'delete';
    this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].addNew = 'addNew';
  });
}
}
```

and I defined it in component.ts:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'title', 'description', 'symbol', 'edit', 'delete', 'add new'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MeasureTypeElemetns>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
```

and returned 0 as array length and my data table is empty:

[image: data table]

do you have any idea?

Comment: If you are getting an array, why are you looping through it and pushing to another array? (Not the answer, but why?)

Comment: It could be that when you call the console.log the call hasn't returned with the information, and the new array's length is still 0. Since it's an asynchronous call, you'd have to make sure to log the length after the HTTP call gets back.

Comment: So where are you trying to access the array? you should be doing it within the .subscribe() method

Comment: console.log() show you updated value (not at the time you call it). To really test it, do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.mp))`. You will probably see empty array because of asynchronous call.

Comment: @AustinTFrench I want to use `mp` array as data source of data table material.

Comment: @AjayReddy I used it as data source of data table material and it returned empty table.

Comment: Show the HTML code where you are using it

Comment: @AjayReddy I've just added some more information. Please check.

Comment: @Gilsdav Yes! that's right. it's empty. so, what's the problem?

Comment: @pjlamb12 Yeah, It's true. how do I make sure HTTP call gets back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pjlamb12, Gilsdav and AjayReddy.

I should do it within subscribe method. so my code should be something like this :

```
  this.mpserv.getall().subscribe(
    x => {
      x.forEach(element => {
        this.mp.push(element);
      });
      this.filltoelements(this.mp);
    },
    err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
    () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification')
  );
```

then it worked properly.